# How to set webbrowser documenttext from another form?

Tags: c#, winforms

i create a simple message box to get user input and set the result into webbrowser of previous form.

this is my `MsgInput` source code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class MsgInput : Form
{
    private readonly Main mainForm;
    public string input_type;
    string script;

    public MsgInput()
    {
        this.mainForm = mainForm;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MsgInput_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (input_type == "echo")
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = "Echo : void echo ( string $arg1 [, string $... ] )";

        }
    }

    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (input_type == "echo")
        {
            script = mainForm.webBrowser1.DocumentText;
            if (chkNewLine.Checked == true)
            {
                script += "\n";
            }
            script += "echo " + txtInput.Text;
            mainForm.webBrowser1.DocumentText = script;
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

and i not add anything in first form just set the webbrowser modifiers to public.
when i debug. null return when i try to submit an text

`Main` Form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace EasyPHP
    {
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void echoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var msg = new MsgInput();
            msg.input_type = "echo";
            msg.Show();
        }

        private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<pre>";
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.mainForm = mainForm;` assigning itself to it. You need the instance of mainform. Pass it in the constructor of `MsgInput`. Also don't give controls public access modifier, you'll regret one day. Instead add a method named `SetWebBrowserText` in mainform and call it( let the mainform itself set the documenttext).

Comment: previously I was also curious why there is a warning saying that `Assignment made to same variable` i think it's useless to assign a same variable. what happend if i change the modifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are getting a null reference exception. it will be useful if you post the main form code. From what i understood, you should be passing in the main form reference and that's why you are getting a null reference.

In your code, change the constructor as below (ParentForm is whatever is the class name of your parent form)

```
public MsgInput(ParentForm mainForm)
        {
            this.mainForm = mainForm;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

and in the main form

```
MsgInput frm = new MsgInput(this);
            frm.input_type = "echo";
            frm.Show(this);
```

Else please share the full code and we can quickly help

Comment: i already update my question and try your solution. its success!
thanks